tuneR package - memory consumption is off charts with only a few wav files
Situation - I need to scan through audio files and get values for bits, sample rate, is track stereo YN, is track PCM YN. I have tried to use the tuneR package to do this. It works, but it comes close to maxing out the memory on my machine after analyzing only a few tracks. To be fair to tuneR, I went out of my way to give it nasty stuff to start - the test batch is 1 track, 3 hours long, 16 bit, 48000 Hz sample rate (1536 kbps) wav file.
The code pasted below did its job, but it also consumed about 10.06 GB of memory. The actual size of the wav file analyzed is 1.97GB. I haven't tried yet, but assume this will be a huge problem when I send it the real work - thousands of wav files, only about 5% in excess of 10 minutes, but thousands all the same.
I want to build a simple table of all tracks in a folder, with fields for filename, pathway, bits, sample rate, is the track stereo YN, is the track PCM YN, mod date, and maybe a few other things I'm not thinking of now. I will use the values for bits, sample rate, and stereo YN to calculate the actual bitrate.
Code is below. I looked around for alternatives to this but did not find any. There must be a way to do this that is far less resource intensive than what I have here...software like winamp (that's right) or Native Instruments Traktor, can do this exponentially faster with far fewer resources consumed.
Can someone please help me with what I'm doing wrong?
install.packages("fs")
install.packages("tuneR")
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(fs)
library(tuneR)
library(tidyverse)


read_wav_metadata <- function(file_path) {
  # Read WAV file
  wav_data <- readWave(file_path)
  
  # Extract metadata
  metadata <- tibble(
    FileName = basename(file_path),
    FilePath = dirname(file_path),
    Bits = wav_data@bit,
    SampleRate = wav_data@samp.rate,
    StereoTF = wav_data@stereo,
    PCTF = wav_data@pcm
  )
  
  return(metadata)
}

# Directory containing audio files
audio_dir <- "C:/full/path/to/folder/"

wav_files <- dir_ls(audio_dir, regexp = "\\.wav$")

# Initialize an empty list to store metadata for each WAV file
metadata_list <- list()

# Iterate over each WAV file, read metadata, and store in the list
for (file in wav_files) {
  metadata_list[[file]] <- read_wav_metadata(file)
}

# Combine metadata for all WAV files into a single data frame
tibble(
  do.call(rbind, metadata_list)) -> metadata_df



Please don't include install.packages("tidyverse") and library(tidyverse), unless your question relies on that specific package. As far as I can see you're only using tibble(), so library(tibble) should suffice, but at that point, why not just use data.frame()?

I think I'd use ffmpeg cmd line for this, dumping out to json or such file type in a bash script (er, power shell script), then read that into R.

AkselA - the rest of the script to do this would make use of other elements of tidyverse, ergo the inclusion. Tibble > data.frame b/c that's my preference. @Chris - that might work but I have no idea how to do what you suggested. I'm looking for a solution within R.

You are expected to simplify and adapt your code to make it easier for us to answer, we call that a [mcve].

As Chris mentions, doing this outside R would be far more efficient. ffmpeg would work, but I find sox easier to use.
One way to implement it would be something like this
v <- system("
soxi 'https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/taunt.wav'
", intern=TRUE)
v <- strsplit(v, ": ")
v <- v[lengths(v) > 0]
v <- trimws(do.call(rbind, v))
v
#      [,1]              [,2]                                                  
# [1,] "Input File"      "'https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/taunt.wav'"
# [2,] "Channels"        "1"                                                   
# [3,] "Sample Rate"     "22257"                                               
# [4,] "Precision"       "8-bit"                                               
# [5,] "Duration"        "00:00:04.10 = 91240 samples ~ 307.454 CDDA sectors"  
# [6,] "File Size"       "0"                                                   
# [7,] "Bit Rate"        "0"                                                   
# [8,] "Sample Encoding" "8-bit Unsigned Integer PCM"                      


If you want to scan multiple files, you can put all the files in a single folder, move to that folder, and call soxi * (or soxi *.wav to only scan WAVs etc.)
v2 <- system("
mkdir -p soundfiles
cd soundfiles
wget -i - << EOF
https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/CantinaBand3.wav
https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/taunt.wav
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg
https://github.com/sfiera/flac-test-files/raw/master/surround51.flac
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Aadama.mp3
EOF
soxi *
", intern=TRUE)
v2 <- strsplit(v2, ": ")
v2 <- v2[lengths(v2) > 0]
v2 <- trimws(do.call(rbind, v2))
v2l <- split.data.frame(v2, cumsum(grepl("^Input File", v2[,1])))
v2l[1:2]
# $`1`
#      [,1]              [,2]                                                 
# [1,] "Input File"      "'Aadama.mp3'"                                       
# [2,] "Channels"        "2"                                                  
# [3,] "Sample Rate"     "44100"                                              
# [4,] "Precision"       "16-bit"                                             
# [5,] "Duration"        "00:00:02.35 = 103679 samples = 176.325 CDDA sectors"
# [6,] "File Size"       "37.9k"                                              
# [7,] "Bit Rate"        "129k"                                               
# [8,] "Sample Encoding" "MPEG audio (layer I, II or III)"                    
# 
# $`2`
#      [,1]              [,2]                                            
# [1,] "Input File"      "'CantinaBand3.wav'"                            
# [2,] "Channels"        "1"                                             
# [3,] "Sample Rate"     "22050"                                         
# [4,] "Precision"       "16-bit"                                        
# [5,] "Duration"        "00:00:03.00 = 66150 samples ~ 225 CDDA sectors"
# [6,] "File Size"       "132k"                                          
# [7,] "Bit Rate"        "353k"                                          
# [8,] "Sample Encoding" "16-bit Signed Integer PCM"                     
# 


And looking at your code above, much easier, and appears to have no appreciable memory overhead as viewed (admittedly on a small wav) by htop. Can you extend your system call to a dir of wav files for the folks at home?

@Chris: You can of course run a loop in R and call soxi multiple times, and that might be more convenient depending on the rest of the workflow, but soxi * is pretty convenient.

On a directory with many audio files, system('soxi /home/chris/cdr_process/*.wav >> crd_rpt2.txt'), then read report with <- read.dcf('crd_rpt2.txt') returns a matrix with named columns, 'Input Files':'Sample Encoding', with dangling 'Total Duration of X files'.

The readWave function has a parameter header that defaults to FALSE. Setting it to TRUE should do the trick. Here's some code that shows the speedup
library(tuneR)

# make a large file
large_wav <- sine(444, duration=1000, xunit='time')
# save two copies so there's no chance of caching affecting the result
writeWave(large_wav, filename = 'large_wav1.wav')
writeWave(large_wav, filename = 'large_wav2.wav')

# Time things
system.time(w1 <- readWave('large_wav1.wav'))
system.time(w2 <- readWave('large_wav2.wav', header=TRUE))

# Delete the files
r <- file.remove('large_wav1.wav')
r <- file.remove('large_wav2.wav')

First call with the default header==FALSE
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.200   0.115   1.314 

Second call with header==TRUE
# user  system elapsed 
#    0       0       0 

The amount of information returned is less so this might be too much of a deficiency to make it usable however.
